# Backup blockchain from a running geth fullnode

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, import, backup, export

I need to make backups from my running node to be able to start a second node quickly or to restore the node quickly if it gets corrupted.
Does `geth export` work on a running node? is it a good option or is `geth import` too slow to get a new node running
what are other options? can I just copy data while the node is running?